# Decoder for Content-Transfer-Encoding and Quoted-printable

Tags: javascript, email, escaping

Below are two utility functions I have written to help decode email messages in [Mbox](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mbox) format. `decodeTransfer` decodes the message according to the [Content-Transfer-Encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Content-Transfer-Encoding) header field. `decodeQuotedPrintable` decodes messages with the [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding.

## Questions

1. Is there a better way to ensure a parameter is of type string than what I have at the moment? i. e.: `if (!(typeof data === "string" || data instanceof String)) return null;`
2. Are format and style of the documentation comments correct?
3. In the `decodeTransfer` function, I do not differentiate between `8bit`, `7bit`, and `binary` `Content-Transfer-Encoding`, because they are the same (apart from allowed size) in my opinion. When only parsing does the difference in maximal allowed size matter (and therefore require an extended decoding function) or can I safely ignore it?
4. The `decodeQuotedPrintable` function seems to pass all my test cases but I don't know if it is missing any features of the [quoted-printable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable) encoding. At the moment it takes care of encoded byte values (e. g.: `=20` is ) and soft line breaks. Are there any others?

### decodeTransfer:

```
/**
 * Decodes the payload of a message.
 * Uses the encoding specified in the "Content-Transfer-Encoding" header field.
 * Returns null if there was an error.
 *
 * @param {string} cte The "Content-Transfer-Encoding" header field of the message.
 * @param {string} payload The payload of the message.
 * @returns {string} The decoded message payload or null if there was an error.
 */
var decodeTransfer = function (cte, payload) {
    // Content-Transfer-Encoding
    // base64, quoted-printable, 8bit, 7bit, binary, x-token
    // ensure that cte is a string
    if (!(typeof cte === "string" || cte instanceof String)) {
        return null;
    }
    // ensure that payload is a string
    if (!(typeof payload === "string" || payload instanceof String)) {
        return null;
    }
    // choose the correct encoding and decode
    switch (cte.toLowerCase()) {
        case "base64":
            // remove all invalid base64 characters and then decode
            return atob(payload.replace(/[^A-Za-z0-9+\/=]/g, ""));
        case "quoted-printable":
            return decodeQuotedPrintable(payload);
            // 8bit, 7bit and binary are basically the same
            // and need not to be decoded
        case "8bit":
        case "7bit":
        case "binary":
            return payload;
        default:
            // x-token or invalid
            return null;
    }
};

// Examples
alert("dT [base64]: " + (decodeTransfer("base64", "x2EgbSfpbmVydmUgIQ==") === "Ça m'énerve !"));
alert("dT [quoted-printable]: " + (decodeTransfer("quoted-printable", "=C3=87a m'=C3=A9nerve !") === "Ça m'énerve !"));
alert("dT [binary]: " + (decodeTransfer("binary", "Ça m'énerve !") === "Ça m'énerve !"));
```

### decodeQuotedPrintable:

```
/**
 * Decodes a quoted-printable encoded string.
 * Returns null if there was an error.
 *
 * https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quoted-printable
 *
 * @param {string} data The quoted - printable encoded data.
 * @returns {string} The decoded string or null if there was an error.
 */
var decodeQuotedPrintable = function (data) {
    // ensure that data is a string
    if (!(typeof data === "string" || data instanceof String)) {
        return null;
    }
    var replacer = function (match, p1) {
        // handle escape sequence
        if (p1.trim().length === 2) {
            // decode byte (for example: "=20" ends up as " ")
            var code = parseInt(p1.trim(), 16);
            return String.fromCharCode(code);
        }
        // handle soft line breaks
        return "";
    };
    // remove soft line breaks and convert escape sequences
    data = data.replace(/=([0-9A-F]{2}|\r\n|\n)/gi, replacer);
    // decode escape sequences
    try {
        return decodeURIComponent(escape(data));
    } catch (dummy) {
        return null;
    }
};

// Example
alert("dQP: " + (decodeQuotedPrintable("=C3=87a m'=C3=A9nerve !") === "Ça m'énerve !"));
```

(The use of libraries is not an option because this code runs as part of a browser extension.)